# How do I write a dry update_output() function for these stages in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, function, dry

So I was offered help with this on another question, but I'm struggling to implement it when my app progresses in complexity...

```
var gender;
var age;
$("#gender :radio").click(function() {
  gender = $(this).val();
  update();
});
$("#age li").click(function() {
  age = $(this).text();
  $('#children').show();
  update();
});


function update() {
  var text = gender || "";
  if (text.length > 0) {
    text += " -> ";
  }
  text += age || "";
  $("span.jquery_out").text(text);
}
```

Which is fine, but I'm wanting to add in 12 variables, and I need to have the update() function clock up in a more desirable way.

My vars are:

```
var gender;
var age;
var children;
var income;
var stage2select;
var day;
var spend;
var categories;
var product;
var price;
var quantity;
var total;
```

How would I get these to cycle through the update() function with " -> " in-between each one, without over using code?

Thanks, Matt.

Comment: Please, please fix your shift key, I'll not edit it for you next time.

Comment: Hi Koning, thanks, but what was the problem, just to be sure i don't do it again??

Comment: You did it again xD You wrote I in lowercase in your comment. The problem is that it's really a pain in the eyes to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your long variable list to an object and then loop the object like this:

```
var myObj = {
    gender:'',
    age:'',
    children:'',
    income:'',
    stage2select:'',
    day:'',
    spend:'',
    categories:'',
    product:'',
    price:'',
    quantity:'',
    total:''
};

$("#gender :radio").click(function() {
    myObj.gender = $(this).val();
    update();
});

$("#age li").click(function() {
    myObj.age = $(this).text();
    $('#children').show();
    update();
});

function update() {
    var text = "";
    $.each(myObj, function(i){
        if (this != ''){
            if (text.length){
                text += " -> ";
            }
            text += this;
        }
    });
    $("span.jquery_out").text(text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, only, "var out" should be "var text" i'm guessing right?